# Wort chiller length, will 30 feet work for a 10 gallon batch?

Tags: chilling, wort-chiller

I just bought 30 feet (~10m) of 3/8'' (9.5mm) copper tube, and before coiling it, I would like to get advice if it will work for a 10 gal (~50l) batch, what I'm asking for is if anyone has had experience cooling 10 gal(~50l) batches with a 25 or 30 feet chiller (I still can go back to the store -which is far away from home- and buy some more tube)

This answer from @BobTheAverage seems to say 30 feet would be ok: [Immersion wort chiller length](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/20543/immersion-wort-chiller-length)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will always work, the difference is how much time we save or not.

My 25' 1/4" wort chiller works better than I expected, 15 minutes to cool 5 gallons.  Your 30' 3/8" should work very well, 15 to 20 minutes maximum I would guess.

Comment: I use 25ft chiller, in a 16gal kettle. and it works for 10 gals. as stated above, it takes longer with that size cooler. if you want faster cooling, then get 50ft. for me average batch is about 15mins like above, but when i did 10 gal. it took about 30mins

Comment: @jsolarski is your tubing 3/8 or 1/4?

Comment: So based on jsolarski's comment, with 30' instead of 25', you should be just under 30 minutes (closer to 25 perhaps).  But again, it will depend on water temperature and if your chiller is partially or completely submerged, etc.

Comment: 1
down vote
 

3/8, but my ground water is pretty cold, 65f on average and i get it to about 80f when i take it out.

Comment: Chilling will be much faster if you stir or recirculate your wort. A 30' 3/8" chiller with recirculation will chill faster than a 50' 1/2" chiller.